# Building apps using .NET Core 2.0.0 Preview 1 on VSTS

Tags: azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to build an app using .NET Core 2.0.0 Preview 1 on VSTS, but I'm getting this error while trying to restore the nuget packages:

```
Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'.
```

Any workaround for this?

Comment: please consider about accepting my answer as the correct one because it got more upvotes than the answer accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you were use Hosted VS2017 agent to queue your build. While Hosted VS2017 agent only has .NET core 1.0.0 installed (you can find installed software [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted#hosted-vs2017)).

The work around to build apps using .NET core 2.0.0, you should use a [private agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows) where the [.NET core 2.0.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/10/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-1/) and Visual Studio 2017 Preview 15.3 is installed.

Comment: How is it that MS STILL fails to sync releases to vsts of final versions of their own tech? There is never a case where VSTS shouldn't have the stuff you're announcing on the day that you're announcing it! 3 days in of .net core 2.0 final and we still can't build with hosted agents! *head bang*

Comment: @JamesHancock Hosted agents only use vs released version. Since 15.3 is still pre-release, so it won't be installed in Hosted VS2017 agent.

Comment: 15.3 ISN'T PRE-RELEASE AS OF MONDAY. And even if it was, .NET Core 2.0 ISN'T EITHER as of MONDAY thus .NET core 2.0 final should have been on the agents ready to build WITHOUT VS.NET which isn't needed for .net core.  These both should have been available to all SAME DAY as public final release.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT VS 15.3 has been officially released on Aug 14 as mentioned on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/08/14/visual-studio-2017-version-15-3-released/ and release notes was also published https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I solved the issue.

1. Use .NET Core Tool Installer (Preview) as the immediate after get source step.
   [image]
2. Use the Nugget feed as next step

[image]

3. Change Restore step to use Feed(s) I select here.

[image]

Finally build steps looks like this.

[image]

Comment: This almost gets me where I want to go, but switching to "feeds I select here," where do I include something like a MyGet feed along side of the normal Nuget?

Comment: you don't have to. You can keep "Use packages from this VSTS/TFS feed" field empty.

Comment: Right, but then it doesn't pick up the one package I need from MyGet.